# Is Spring AOP the easiest solution for crosscut logging of Http requests (inbound and outbound)?

Tags: spring, logging, spring-integration, aop

I wanted to check to see if I hadn't missed another option for logging.

I want to be able to add logging of HTTP input requests and HTTP output requests without having to add explicit logging constructs just before/after each call.  AOP seems to be a way of doing this.  Is there another fashion?  I was also looking at wiretap/global channel interceptors but this would not appear to apply to inbound-endpoints and outbound-endpoints.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What is the "easiest" solution, is in the eye of the beholder and a type of question which does not have a correct answer, but rather leads to opinionated discussions. Therefore, I think it is off-topic here on SO. You should either rephrase it and ask a concrete question together with actual code you have problems with, or delete it. No offence meant.

Comment: Whereas I agree that the question as stated is subjective, I do think that the answers provided up to now are useful, hence I'll not delete the question.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't say that the **answers** are not useful. I am saying that the **question** is off topic. Your second question here, basically about the same topic, was more focused and concrete and therefore got a concrete answer.

Comment: There you have it!  Because the first question informed the second question.  There was no second question without the first question.  QED.

Answer (score 2):

You could log inbound requests and outbound responses with a `javax.servlet.Filter` implementing class.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class logFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        
                        System.out.println("Inbound request "  + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
                        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                        System.out.println("Outbound response "  + httpServletResponse.getStatus());

        
        }
}
```

Comment: That will work for inbound-endpoint but I'm thinking would not apply to outbound-endpoint.

Comment: @al.truisme what do you mean with outbound-endpoint? Do you mean a http request that is made by your application?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  For instance, with outbound-gateway in the HTTP namespace.

Comment: @al.truisme Are you using `RestTemplate` to make the outgoing http requests? This [tutorial on baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-logging) explains how you can log outgoing http requests made with `RestTemplate`

Comment: I'm using spring-integration's http:output-gateway for http.  That's an interesting article, though, thanks very much.

Comment: Spring Integration HTTP module is fully based on Spring MVC for the inbound endpoints and on the `RestTemplate` on the outbound side. So, it is fully legit to instrument MVC and `RestTemplate` for your integration configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http